# NGINX - Regex into locations.conf doesn't work

Tags: regex, spring-boot, nginx, proxy

I have an issue into the configuration of my nginx proxy. 
I just try to use regex has it is defined here: https://underthehood.meltwater.com/blog/2017/12/12/lightweight-tests-for-your-nginx-api-gateway/

But nothing works. My server won't start if it is any regex into the path. 
I tried:

```
location ~ ^/tesla/(?<id>.*)$ {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
 proxy_set_header        Host                  $host;
}
```

or

```
location ~ ^/tesla/test/ {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
 proxy_set_header        Host                  $host;
}
```

or

```
location ~* ^/tesla/test/ {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
 proxy_set_header        Host                  $host;
}
```

Nothing work. My final aim is to extract a value from the url and do the following thing:

```
location ~* ^/(<version>.*)/test/ {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
 proxy_set_header        Host                  $host;
 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Prefix    $version;
}
```

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

I finally succeed thanks to [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith).
Here is the complete code:

```
location ~* ^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*/.*)$   {
  proxy_pass  http://$service.localnetwork:8080$3;
  proxy_set_header        Host                  $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Prefix    /api/$version/$service;
  proxy_set_header        msvc_name    $service;
  proxy_set_header        msvc_version    $version;
}
```

Comment: The route of my apis comes after "^/(<version>.*)/test/". Example: http://localhost:8080/alpha/test/api/books. I want to keep the version and inject it into the X-Forwarded-Prefix in order to make Spring and Hateoas (apis behind are made of Spring Boot) handle correctly the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `proxy_pass` with a static URI within a regular expression `location` block, it will throw an error - see your Nginx error log. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

However, you can construct the URI to send upstream by appending variables to the `proxy_pass` statement. In your case, you could capture the remainder of the URI in the same regular expression.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/([^/]+)/test(/.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081$2;
    proxy_set_header  Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Prefix  $1;
}
```